# how to freeze the index column in pandas.describe()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

[freeze the index column in jupyter-notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2zIj.png)

Hi guys, I have a question: how can I freeze the first column (index) of the table pandas.describe()? The content in the red box in the picture

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze"?

Comment: When I scroll the table left or right, the first column must not be moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any way to do this with pandas alone in jupyter. That said, several tools exist for displaying pandas dataframes in jupyter notebooks in more complex ways (e.g. freezing the first column). Some suggestions follow:

- [ipyaggrid](https://gitlab.com/DGothrek/ipyaggrid)
- [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid)

Personally, I have had great experience with `ipyaggrid`. Feel free to comment on this answer if you try using `ipyaggrid` and cannot achieve your desired frozen column effect -- happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.describe().style.set_sticky()
```